# Import "torch" could not be resolved, torch=1.10.2 installed

Tags: python, computer-vision, yolov5

I am trying to run the `detect.py` file from https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5#tutorials, but vscode says `Import "torch" could not be resolved`. I checked with `pip list` and it says

```
torch                   1.10.2
torchvision             0.11.3
```

I have also installed CUDA v11.6 and added it to environment variables. What is my issue here?

This is my first post so let me know if there is any additional information needed and I will be happy to provide it.

**EDIT:** I resolved this issue through going outside of my virtual environment and using `pip install torch` and `pip install torchvision` in my C:\Users\username directory. I noticed that OpenCV needs the same thing. I guess any package that directly interfaces with your computer's components needs to be installed outside of the virtual environment.

Comment: are you sure you're using the same python env for both? E.g. if you're using something like conda or virtualenv, then you might be installing the package in one env while using another env for executing your code.

Comment: Have you run the code below?  
!git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5  # clone repo
%cd yolov5
%pip install -qr requirements.txt  # install dependencies